# Meteor and Angular adding $mongoObject

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am following the angular tutorial [HERE](http://angularjs.meteor.com/tutorial/step_06), but when I get to step 6 and try to add the `$mongoObject` using:

```
angular.module("socially").controller("PartyDetailsCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$meteorObject',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $meteorObject) {
        $scope.party = $meteorObject(Parties, $stateParams.partyId);
    }
]);
```

I get the following error

[image]

Comment: Are you missing any script files? Can you provide your `ng-app` declaration?

Comment: @salniro it seems like it is a angular-meteor package issue https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/120#issuecomment-69478849

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run

```
meteor update
```

to update to the latest version.

Let me know if it worked,

Good luck